# Can't write files in python when I run it's .py file. But when I run it in pycharm, it actually work

Tags: python, file, pycharm

I'am still new in python and im having a hard time why does my py file wont write text when i run it its .py file. But whenever i run it on pycharm it always works. I also tried many option when writing on a file and it still won't write anything in file unless i run it on Pycharm. Am i missing something? pleasee need help

[here the .py file im telling whenever i  run this, nothing happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUxgB.png)

```
path = 'wifipasswords.txt'
my_open = open(path, 'w+')
my_open.write(final_output)
print(final_output)
my_open.close()


//MY attempts
# with open("wifipasswords.txt", "w") as f:
#     print(final_output, file=f)

# pathlib.Path("wifipasswords.txt").write_text(final_output)
# with open("wifipasswords.txt", "w") as f:
#     f.write(final_output)

# file = open("wifipasswords.txt", "w")
# file.write(final_output)
# file.close()
```

Comment: Do you get an error when you try to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly an issue of your working directory. The location of the script does not imply that that is where the file will be created, and you're probably looking in the wrong place for the resulting file. Add a line to your script:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

then check if `wifipasswords.txt` is in that directory (it should be). If you want to explicitly place the file in the same directory as the script (not a good idea in general since scripts are often installed in protected locations, but okay for personal use), you can explicitly change the working directory with something like:

```
import os
import os.path

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

or explicitly qualify the file name without changing your working directory, e.g.:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'wifipasswords.txt')
```

Comment: @newbeeSyntax: You're welcome. I'd suggest performing the first check as well, and figure out where else on your file system you've been dumping your passwords. Or just search the whole disk, since you might have dumped them in multiple places. :-)

Comment: Literally just add the `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` to the very top of your file (before `chdir`, if that's the approach you used) to see where it was going. If you mean how to search your whole disk, on Windows in a `cmd.exe` session, do `C:` (or whatever drive you want to search), `cd \ `, then `dir /s /b wifipasswords.txt`. On most other UNIX-y systems, `find / -type f -name wifipasswords.txt` will do it. Might take a while in both cases, but you can just let it run and check back later.

Comment: it says int th C:\WINDOWS\System32  and i tried it in  cmd 
C:\WINDOWS\System32 cd\ /dir s wifipasswords.txt    howerver it says in the cmd 'C:\WINDOWS\System32' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. I just really appreciate your help dude i hope i could vote now to upvote, but i still cant since this is just my first timme assking in here. HAHAHAH tahnk you dude

Comment: @newbeeSyntax: You need to run each component separately. So bring up `cmd.exe`, then in resulting window type each command, hit Enter, one by one, to find the files. When you find them, it's probably easier for you to use the normal folder Explorer to get to each directory and delete them, though if you're comfortable with it, running `del C:\WINDOWS\System32\wifipasswords.txt` (or whatever the full paths from `dir` returned) would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that:

1. you are running python main **.py**
2. that you don't have python2 and python3 installed together, resulting that maybe "python.exe" in PATH variable is actually python2. If you do, edit path variable.

Comment: i only intalled python 3.8  and nothing else since it is just my firstime using it, I just dont seems to understand why does it works on pycharm but not on its actual exe file :/

Comment: i also tried it to run in python 3.8 console. It prints the result but not just writing it on the file tho :/